# Using a Form to Filter a Crosstab Query MS Access 2010

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010, pivot, crosstab

I am using Access 2010.  I have a crosstab query that I am trying to filter based on the value of a Text box on a Form.  The full SQL is as below:

```
PARAMETERS Forms!SelectForm!Text27 DateTime;

TRANSFORM nz(Sum([Raw Contract Data].[Action Obligation]), 0) AS [SumOfAction Obligation]

SELECT [Raw Contract Data].[NAICS Code], [Raw Contract Data].[NAICS Description], Sum([Raw
Contract Data].[Action Obligation]) AS [Total Of Action Obligation], NZ(round(avg([SumOfAction 
Obligation]),0),) AS [Average Obligation], 
nz(round(stdev([SumOfAction Obligation]),0),0) AS [StDev of CTRs], 
nz(round(var([SumOfAction Obligation]),0),0) AS [Variance of Obligations]

FROM [Raw Contract Data]

WHERE [Raw Contract Data].[Date Signed]  <= Forms!SelectForm!Text27

GROUP BY [Raw Contract Data].[NAICS Code], [Raw Contract Data].[NAICS Description]

PIVOT format([Raw Contract Data].[Date Signed], "yyyy-mm");
```

The problem is that the query will run but a box pops up asking for the value of Text 27.  It won't recognize it from the value that is in it on the form.  The WHERE clause will work when I manually type in a date (without the preceding PARAMETERS declaration) but when I want it to reference the value of the text field I get nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to this method and let me know if this helps you

```
PARAMETERS EnterDate DateTime;
TRANSFORM nz(Sum([Raw Contract Data].[Action Obligation]), 0) AS [SumOfAction Obligation]
SELECT [Raw Contract Data].[NAICS Code], [Raw Contract Data].[NAICS Description],
Sum([RawContract Data].[Action Obligation]) AS [Total Of Action Obligation],
NZ(round(avg([SumOfAction Obligation]),0),) AS [Average Obligation],
nz(round(stdev([SumOfAction Obligation]),0),0) AS [StDev of CTRs],
nz(round(var([SumOfAction Obligation]),0),0) AS [Variance of Obligations]
FROM [Raw Contract Data]
WHERE [Raw Contract Data].[Date Signed]  <= EnterDate
GROUP BY [Raw Contract Data].[NAICS Code], [Raw Contract Data].[NAICS Description]
PIVOT format([Raw Contract Data].[Date Signed], "yyyy-mm");
```

Save this query say name **Query1**

On Filter action say **on** **clicking filter button** define the following code

```
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim rst as DAO.Recordset
Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("Query1")
qdf!EnterDate = Forms!SelectForm!Text27
Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset
Set rst = Nothing
Set qdf = Nothing
```

Comment: is it possible to do it with a macro instead of vba?

Answer (score 0):

Remember you must have form in open state from which you are referring the **Text27**

Otherwise whenever you execute query, query doesn't get the parameter value because the form is not opened and it will ask you for the value of **Text27**.

Comment: Yeah.  I have it in Open State.